How do you create a new dataset of averages from specific rows of data?
I have a 3000+ row dataset, and some of the column titles are:
Survey_Date, Year, Quarter, Site_Name, Quadrat, Species, (several columns of data values)
Transect surveys were completed for each species on 5 different sites, each with 12 permanent quadrats that have been measured every quarter (roughly each season) over the last 12 years.
Sample of first 24 rows:
CL.SGN.Data <- structure(list(Species = c("Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica"), Survey_Date = structure(c(1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Year = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012"), Quarter = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), Site_Name = c("Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay"), Quad = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", 
"Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", 
"Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12"), Cover = c(0.75, 
0.75, 0.45, 0.65, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Calculated_Density = c(65, 
60, 26, 20, 3.75, 9, 9, 16, 8, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Average_Height = c(46.6666666666667, 39.9, 42, 
53.5, 41.6666666666667, 40, 48.8333333333333, 54.6666666666667, 
66, 30.5, 47.5, 50, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
test

The data is arranged so that one survey is represented by every 12 rows.
I want to create a new data frame (or tibble) for each survey at each site with an average of the data across the 12 quadrats, so that each survey only has one average measure, instead of 12 separate ones.
R Studio version 4.3.1
I've considered nesting the data through tidyverse, however I can't seem to fully comprehend the process, nor do I know if that's a possibility.
I started to brute force the data for each quarter, and can arrive at one line of mean values for each measure
library(tidyverse)
BB_ZM_2013_Q1 <- CL.SGN.DATA %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Site_Name, "Birch Bay"),
         str_detect(Species, "Z. marina"),
         str_detect(Year, "2013"),
         str_detect(Quarter, "1")) %>% 
  mutate(Mean.Cover = mean(Cover),
         Mean.Height = mean(Average_Height),
         Mean.Density = mean(Calculated_Density)) %>% 
  select(Species, Year, Quarter, Site_Name, Mean.Cover, Mean.Height, Mean.Density) %>% 
  slice_head()

BB_ZM_2013_Q2 <- CL.SGN.DATA %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Site_Name, "Birch Bay"),
         str_detect(Species, "Z. marina"),
         str_detect(Year, "2013"),
         str_detect(Quarter, "2")) %>% 
  mutate(Mean.Cover = mean(Cover),
         Mean.Height = mean(Average_Height),
         Mean.Density = mean(Calculated_Density)) %>% 
  select(Species, Year, Quarter, Site_Name, Mean.Cover, Mean.Height, Mean.Density) %>% 
  slice_head()
 

This output two new dataframes of just one row.
I then tried to create a data frame, however it just kept it as one row and added more columns.
BB_ZM <- data.frame(BB_ZM_2013_Q1, BB_ZM_2013_Q2)

(I know I could tinker with this last one to make it work, not sure how yet).
Larger problem is that I really don't want to brute force it this way if there is an easier solution. I just can't seem to find it.

This sounds like a standard "mean by group", CL.SGN.DATA |> summarize(across(Cover:Average_Height, mean), .by = c(Species, Survey_Date, Year, Quarter, Site_Name)) to take the mean of all columns from Cover to Average_Height, grouped by all the rest of the columns except Quad.

Maybe L.SGN.DATA |> summarize(across(Cover:Average_Height, \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = c(Species, Survey_Date, Year, Quarter, Site_Name)) since you've got NA values.

@GregorThomas Both of these options work! I appreciate it!
I messed with it a bit, based on a similar suggestion and ended up with this:
Not sure how to add the code chunk in comments
CL.SGN.DATA %>%
filter(str_detect(Species, "Z. marina")) %>%
filter(!is.na(Calculated_Density),
!is.na(Average_Height),
!is.na(Cover)) %>%
summarize(across(c(Cover, Average_Height, Calculated_Density), mean), .by = c(Site_Name, Survey_Date))

Your approach might be appropriate for your situation, but note that you are deleting every row that has any missing values, which might be rejecting useful info if any of the rows are only partly missing.

Also a comment that str_detect is needed if you want to search inside strings for a patter, like str_detect("My species is Z. marina", "Z. marina"). You are testing for an exact match of an entire string, you you can use filter(Species == "Z. marina"), no need for str_detect().

Also, if rather than doing each species individually, if you want separate data frames take my code and put |> group_split(Species) at the end to get a list of data frames for each species, and if you really want separate data frames tack on |> list2env() to put them in your environment. No need to copy/paste the same code for each species. See my answer at How to make a list of data frames? for more context.

@JonSpring you are correct, I am planning on using select in the piping to only remove rows where their removal would omit data not gathered to prevent unnecessary loss of data. That said, I may abandon that code in favor of some of what Gregor is saying...

@GregorThomas You are a legend. Thank you so much.

Grouping by the variable to describe a unique survey then taking themean across quadrats can be done in a tidyverse pipe. In this case I grouped by year and quarter instead of date in case your larger data set has some plots where data was collected over multiple days.
CL.SGN.Data_Summary <- CL.SGN.Data %>%
  group_by(Species, Year, Quarter, Site_Name) %>%
    summarise(across(.cols=Cover:Average_Height,.fns=\(x) mean(x, na.rm=T) ))


The comments above helped me resolve this, but for curiousity on alternative approaches, I tried this and ended with the warning message:
"Warning: 'summarise' is deprecated.
Use 'LRstats' instead.
See help("Deprecated")Error in across():
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like mutate(), filter(), and group_by().
Backtrace:

... %>% ...
dplyr::across(.cols = Cover:Average_Height, .fns = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))
Error in across(.cols = Cover:Average_Height, .fns = function(x) mean(x, :"


Strange, based on that error is seems like another package is using the summarise/summarize function, try using dplyr::summarise() instead.

What does this answer add over the comments given below the question?

There was not the same amount of comments when I submitted it, it entered as an answer so the question can be marked as answered, grouping done on a separate function, and defined .cols= and .fns= in the across part to make it a little more obvious what each of those options is doing?

The first two comments freom Gregor Thomas are older...
